# To find the set of values of $x$ that satisfy both inequations $5x+2<3x+8$ and $\dfrac{x+2}{x-1}<4$.

Tags: inequality

To find the set of values of $x$ that satisfy both inequations $5x+2<3x+8$ and $\dfrac{x+2}{x-1}<4$.

My attempt:

$5x+2<3x+8 \implies 2x<6 \implies x<3\qquad (1)$

$\dfrac{x+2}{x-1}<4 \implies x+2<4(x-1) \implies x+2<4x-4 \implies 6<3x \implies x>2\qquad(2)$

Denominator as zero

$x-1=0 \implies x=1\qquad (3)$

Could you tell me if it is correct what I wrote? Please, correct my mistakes.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 1):

The chain you have followed in $(1)$ is correct, so from the inequality $$5x+2<3x+8 \implies \dots \implies x<3 \tag1$$ your conclusion is correct.

However, the step of multiplying $x-1$ to both sides of the inequality in $(2)$ in your approach, is not foolproof, because $a>b \implies ac>bc$ only if $c>0$, i.e. you can multiply $(x-1)$ to both sides of the inequality keeping the sign of inequality unchanged only if you are sure that $x-1$ is positive. 
 What you can do is $$\begin{aligned} \dfrac{x+2}{x-1}<4 &\implies \dfrac{x+2}{x-1}-4<0 \\ &\implies \dfrac{x+2-4x+4}{x-1}>0 \\ &\implies \dfrac{-3x+6}{x-1}>0 \\ \implies (-3x+6) \text{ and } (x-1) &\text{ need to be of the same sign} \\ \implies \text{either } -3x+6>0, (x-1)>0 &\implies 3x<6, x>1 \\ &\implies x<2,x>1 \\ &\implies 1<x<2 \\ \text{or } -3x+6<0, (x-1)<0 &\implies 3x>6, x<1 \\ &\implies x>2,x<1 \\ &\implies \text{no such }x\text{ is possible}  \end{aligned}\tag2$$

Thus, we have from $(1)$, $\boxed{-\infty < x< 3}$ 
and from $(2)$, $\boxed{1<x<2}$ 
and we need $x$ satisfying both these conditions, so note that all the $x$ satisfying the second box satisfy the condition in the first box, but not the other way round. Basically, you need to take the intersection of the solution sets for both inequalities $(-\infty,3)\cap (1,2)=(1,2)$, so the set of $x$ satisfying both inequalities is the interval $(1,2)$, i.e. all $x$ strictly greater than $1$ and strictly lesser than $2$.

**Note:** The zero-denominator problem is not there anymore.